# enzyme shallowWrapper.setState not working for redux connected components

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme

**KINDLY READ BEFORE MARKING IT AS DUPLICATE**

So, I went through all the suggested questions and did almost 2 days research on finding out the reason behind my problem.

Here is what I have -

**1.** A component named SignIn with some local state connected to redux store.

```
class SignIn extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isLoading: false };
  }
  render () {
    isLoading
    ? <SomeLoadingComponent />
    : <MainSigninComponent />
  }
}
export default ConnectedSignIn = connect(mapStateToProps)(SignIn);
```

Now as you can see the render output of SignIn changes with the change in local state and I intend to snapshot test both the output.

So I wrote two test cases.

```
// This one is alright as it test on the default state and renders the actual SigninComponent.
test(`it renders correctly`, () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<ConnectedSignIn {...props} />, { context: { store }});

  // .dive() because I intend to snapshot my actual SignIn component and not the connect wrapper.
  expect(wrapper.dive()).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Now when I intend to change the state to *{ isLoading: true }* I fire a call to setState like this in second test.

```
test(`it renders the loading view on setting isLoading state to true`, () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<ConnectedSignIn {...props} />, { context: { store }});

  console.log(wrapper.dive().state()) // returns { isLoading: false }

  // Again .dive because I want to call setState on my SignIn component

  wrapper.dive().setState({ isLoading: true });
  console.log(wrapper.dive().state()) // still returns { isLoading: false }

  // Tried the callback method to ensure async op completion
  wrapper.dive().setState({ isLoading: true }, () => {
    console.log(wrapper.dive().state()) // still returns { isLoading: false }
  });
});
```

So going by above code and output, I infer that the shallow wrapper's setState is not working properly, as in not actually updating the state of component.

Just to mention,

**1.** I also tried using wrapper.dive().instance().setState()
 as I read it in some question that to update the state of instance, this way would be better. ***Did not work.***

**2.** I also tried forcing update on shallowed component using wrapper.update() and wrapper.dive().update(). This one also didn't work.

**My dependency versions**

"react": "16.0.0",

"react-native": "0.50.0",

"react-redux": "^5.0.6",

"enzyme": "^3.3.0",

"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",

"jest": "21.2.1",

"react-dom": "^16.2.0"

I have already read guides on testing components in isolation by separating them from redux. I did that and my test cases ran fine but I wish to know whether this behaviour is normal or a bug and if someone has been successful in testing state changes as well as render changes of a redux connected component then kindly let me know your approach.

Comment: Strange, no one has even tried.

Answer (score 6):

Every time you use `dive()` it creates a new wrapper, so all of your calls are referencing a new wrapper rather than the one you updated. Instead, you could try this:

```
test(`it renders the loading view on setting isLoading state to true, () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<ConnectedSignIn {...props} />, { context: { store }});
  const component = wrapper.dive()

  component.setState({ isLoading: true });
  console.log(component.state()) // should be {isLoading: true}
});
```

For reference, see [Jordan Harband's answer](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/1570#issuecomment-403234855) to [this Enzyme issue](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/1570).

Answer (score 2):

This is bad practice. You should test `SignIn` and `ConnectedSignIn` independently.

**1.** Create a named export.

```
// SignIn.js

export class SignIn extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isLoading: false
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { isLoading } = this.state;

    return (
      (isLoading) ? <SomeLoadingComponent /> : <MainSigninComponent />
    );
  }
}

export default ConnectedSignIn = connect(mapStateToProps)(SignIn);
```

**2.** Import the `SignIn` component using the following syntax.

```
import { SignIn } from 'SignIn.js'
```

Notice we import `SignIn` instead of `ConnectedSignIn`.

Comment: I couldn't aggree more. Have already adopted the above mentioned practice but still curious about the reason for the problem mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code. Worked for me.

```js
const newWrapper = wrapper.dive();
console.log(newWrapper.state()) // returns { isLoading: false };
newWrapper.setState({
  isLoading: true
});
console.log(newWrapper.state()) // returns { isLoading: true }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you already know how React setState works, why need to test it? IMO it's better to test the DOM changes triggered by the state change itself.

For your problem, I think you want to redeclare the wrapper:

```
  component = wrapper.find(Component);
  component.props().onSomeChange();
  wrapper.update();
  
  component = wrapper.find(Component) // redeclare since the component has changed
  expect(assertion);
```